# What is the easy way to show only 4 digits after decimal point by default inside textboxes in html

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, asp.net

I have some textboxes which are bind to decimal fields of a view model in cshtml file. Most of them have nine zeros after decimal. I want to show only 4 digits by default while editing them. However, I don't want to fix the length after decimal. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Why wouldn't your view model already have the value calculated to the correct number of digits before it reaches the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest doing at c# controller or where you bind data to UI control like:

```
String.Format("{0:0.0000}", 123.456789012); // 123.4568
```

You can aslo do it in native javascript like :

```
var num = 123.456789012;
var n = num.toFixed(4); // 123.4568
```

Comment: I had to use jquery, so thanks for the javascript suggestion

Answer (score 1):

```
var n = 56767.87488958865
console.log(n.toFixed(4)) //56767.8748
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use CultureInfo in C#.

```
CultureInfo nfi = new CultureInfo("en-US", False);
nfi.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 2;
nfi.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
nfi.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator = "";
nfi.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalDigits = 2;
nfi.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
nfi.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = "";

//Now you can show the data like
txtValue.Text = data.ToString("N", nfi); //Format as number
txtValue.Text = data.ToString("C", nfi); //Format as currency
```

Maybe this will help you in the right direction